# Problem with Gradle and importing existing flutter project to android studio

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to clone this project from github to android studio

https://github.com/X-Wei/flutter_catalog

but it says a problem with the gradle and cant equal null.

i have tried importing using gradle and android gradle but still get the same output.

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\Jay\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_catalog2\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Jay\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_catalog2\android\app\build.gradle' line: 61
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > path may not be null or empty string. path='null'
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
  Command: C:\Users\Jay\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_catalog2\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.